# How to prevent the default home rewrite to a static page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, frontpage

I'm looking for a way to prevent the default behaviour (when you have a static page set as the site homepage or 'frontpage' (in `settings>reading>front page displays` );

I want the `domain.com/` page to point here (as it does), but if I made a page `home`, which would otherwise live at `domain.com/home` Wordpress automatically redirects to `domain.com`, and so there's no way of visiting and staying on `domain.com/home`.

Does anyone have a clue how/where to do this? I've tried investigating php `$_SERVER` variables and attempting to alter rewrite rules, but I don't find a rule therein that matches this situation reliably. (There is one rule to a page with the `home` page `id`, but then I cannot target this reliably (and I think it's actually routing `domain.com/` -> `domain.com/home`.)

To reiterate (and perhaps clarify), how does one make the wordpress 'frontpage' available at the domain root (as is default and working), but also at the page's default permalink also...

Comment: Why is it so important for the page to be called `/home`!? You could try making a static page in the root folder `/home/index.php` if you really need it?

Comment: please explain the reason for doing anything like that? why don't you just call your home page something else?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the home page is called. We've a specific use case where we need to be able to view the home page both at domain.com and domain.com/home but yet discern between the two for some functionality.

Comment: I realise i could set up two home pages... home and home2 and achieve this by setting home2 as the frontpage, but that's not really maintainable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The redirect is thanks to [`redirect_canonical()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical) - we can simply swoop in with a filter and disable it for the front page:

```
function wpse_184163_disable_canonical_front_page( $redirect ) {
    if ( is_page() && $front_page = get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
        if ( is_page( $front_page ) )
            $redirect = false;
    }

    return $redirect;
}

add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'wpse_184163_disable_canonical_front_page' );
```

Now you can access the front page at the root **and** by it's slug, no redirect.

Comment: Perfect! I knew there'd be a hook somewhere, but all my googlings didn't turn up anything. Thanks so much, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly you just need your `domain.com/home` to display your homepage too? Just create this in a folder called `home` in the same folder as your `/wp-content` etc

Name it index.php

```
?php
    header("Location: http://domain.com");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: The problem is getting that without the URL changing (so domain.com/home is still displayed. I hadn't thought of this though... It doesn't achieve exactly what I'm after, but could be a good jump off point. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't really be sure how to do it without the url changing - unless perhaps you changed the `header` to just `include` and point it at your `home.php` ?

Comment: Yeh, i was thinking of that. A query for the page that is front_page, and then set that as post and include should replicate everything. Only thing is if the page is called something other than 'home', which could be. It becomes untenable.